# Local Dependency in Gem .gemspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, dependencies

I am working on a gem (Gem A) which uses another gem (Gem B) that I have also written. Until this point Gem B has been added in the gemspec for Gem A:

```
gem.add_dependency "gem_a", "~> 0.0.4"
```

But I now find the need to debug using my local version.

To declare a local dependency in a Gemfile I could do:

```
gem 'gem_a', path: "/local/path/to/gem_a"
```

**But how do I declare a local dependency in a `.gemspec`?**

Comment: Not sure if this can be done, but it would be useful if gems are being co-developed. Trouble is the two declarations of dependency are for two different installers to process. What would `gem build` do with a local dependency? The resulting package couldn't be reliably distributed.

Answer (score 21):

Just so folks can find the answer (slightly) faster...

If you're creating a gem, and need to add a local dependency (while developing), in your *gem's* Gemfile, do something like:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Specify your gem's dependencies in mygem.gemspec
gemspec

gem "local_gem", path: "/path/to/local_gem"
```

When you `bundle` you should see it's now using the local path

```
Using local_gem 0.1.0 from source at `/path/to/local_gem`
```

Comment: Late to the party - but, if I develop a gem locally, then `gem install my_new_gem.gem` to install it locally, I still cannot add it as a dependency in a `gemspec` file right?  It appears that installing a gem locally doesn't  really do anything?

Answer (score 4):

Hm...what about adding it in gem's `Gemfile` in `:development` group?

UPD:
I found similar question, maybe this helps

[How to add dependency of a local gem to a rails plugin/engine, in .gemspec file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678957/how-to-add-dependency-of-a-local-gem-to-a-rails-plugin-engine-in-gemspec-file)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't work. I've tried it before and after the `gemspec` call. For some reason it can't see the gem - I get a '…  in `require': cannot load such file -- gem_b (LoadError)'